# H265 support on WebRTC Android

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264, live-streaming, janus

Am using Janus for WebRTC live streaming. When we are using H264 stream its working but switching to H265 causing Sdp error -

"**Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters..**"

The same is observed on changing the H264 profile from baseline to main. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2023, I think that the only web browser that supports H265 in WebRTC is Safari and the capability is well hidden in the Develop -> Experimental Features -> WebRTC H265 Codec. H265 is not listed among the mandatory codecs for WebRTC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/WebRTC_codecs) so the support is optional. Currently, even the Safari implementation on MacOS requires non-standard headers to make it work and it's well described here: https://github.com/AlexxIT/Blog/issues/5. A C# implementation (disclaimer: I am the author) can be found here: https://github.com/jimm98y/SharpRTSPtoWebRTC

Comment: I also recommend checking out https://caniuse.com/?search=h265 for updated information.

* Safari indeed has the best support for H265 / HEVC. 
* Edge and Chrome has similar support, but depends of custom configuration, local drivers and more. From my experience, it does not work out of the box.

But webrtc implementation itself is not fully supported as said.

Note: Information based on the knowledge at the moment that I'm writing this.